# CakePHP, find() with table alias

Tags: database, cakephp, model, alias

I want to copy 4 tables, deep associated:

```
 Test->Scale->Question->Option
```

into

```
TestResult->ScaleResult->QuestionResult->OptionResult
```

In TestResult and OptionResult I want to add some new columns and also I need to have id of each 'has many' table to put it into each of 'belongs to' table.

So when I use `find()` I want to add aliases to result returned by Cake.

Comment: Please update your question with real names, and clarify why.

Comment: It is possible... though if you explain why you want to do that, the solutions provided will be more applicable to your case.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that is possible. You can provide the alias in the $hasMany, $belongsTo, etc.

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'ImagesAlias' => array(
        'className' => 'Image',
        'foreignKey' => 'car_id'
    )
);
```

You can read everything about it in the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#associations-linking-models-together)

Comment: I know that, but in my case I want to add them only in this particular query